# how to draw contour(rectangle) on next frame with contour already present in previous frame

Tags: opencv

I am doing project in Image processing using opencv library. I want to track the motion of ball such that next frame hi-lights the position of ball in all the previous frames.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials that explain how you can identify a ball shaped object in an image. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: ball is just example.when we use motion tracking algorithms available it does current_frame-previous frame and then hi lights its current position only. But how can I hi light its position in all previous frames?

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to hold your history in a container, `std::deque` is a possible solution:

```
std::deque<Rect> history;
const int HISTORY_SIZE = 10;
```

To draw the history, simply iterate through it inside your running loop:

```
Rect curr = yourTrackingAlgorithm();
history.push_front(curr);

for (int i = 0; i < history.size(); i++)
{
    drawRectangle(history[i]);
}
if (history.size() > HISTORY_SIZE)
{
    history.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: Am still not clear how to use this function. Can you share any one code with this function.